# Exclude pages by menu order

Tags: pages, wp-list-pages, exclude, menu-order

i have a "Default Page Generator" on theme activation i have created...
in that file i set 'menu_order' for each page.

**i want to exclude pages with menu order bigger then 50 from the default wp_list_pages menu**

Is there a way to check for / retrieve 'menu_order' of each page? and if there is can you think of a way to intergrate it into the wp_list_pages function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the following function in your functions.php

```
function wpse58346_wp_list_pages( $pages, $r ) {
    foreach( $pages as $key => $page ) {
        if ( 50 < $page->menu_order )
            unset($pages[$key]);
    }
    return $pages;
}
```

Now before calling `wp_list_pages()` apply a filter as follows

```
add_filter('get_pages', 'wpse58346_wp_list_pages', '', 2);
```

And after you have called `wp_list_pages()` you can remove the filter so that it doesn't mess with some other funcctionality

```
remove_filter('get_pages', 'wpse58346_wp_list_pages');
```

Comment: gr8 job man... easy to implement and easy to use - thanks :)